# Unix programming headerfile details

Tags: unix, documentation, header-files, time.h

I'm very new to the programming field. Right now I'm trying out some basic programs in Linux. Today I've started off with time functions in `time.h`, but I'm getting stuck occasionally. I've done the following code to get a delay in seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay_sec ( int seconds );

int main()
{
    printf ( "\nhaii\n" );
    delay_sec ( 5 );
    printf ( "\nbyee\n" );

    return 0;
}

void delay_sec ( int seconds )
{
    time_t t1 = time ( NULL );
    while ( ( time ( NULL ) - t1 ) < seconds )
         ;
}
```

It works for me. But I need a delay in milliseconds. I've read the `time.h` manual, tried out a few of the functions defined there also, but nothing works like I've expected. The thing is that I actually didn't get any idea about what those functions does.

My question is nothing but where can I find something like a documentation of all the functions and details of arguments, return value, I mean a user manual of all the functions defined in all header files.

I don’t believe something like that really exist, but if you people help me to find something close to that, I would be extremely grateful.

I'm planning to learn fork, pipe, signals, process, thread etc..., I know it's a long way to go. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the POSIX standard `sleep` function, instead of your busy waiting `delay_sec` ... (and use `usleep` for microseconds delay, or better yet `nanosleep`)

I suggest to install the man pages for development (e.g. `manpages-dev` package on Debian or Ubuntu).

Otherwise, look e.g. at [the sleep(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) here.

I strongly suggest reading some good book on [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and then read some book on [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and then some good book on POSIX threads.

Also learn more on Wikipedia about [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), [System calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) etc etc

Comment: An additional resource: [POSIX 2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) documentation.  This tells you what is standard and what is not; it may help you keep your code portable (if portable is an issue, which it may not be yet, but likely will be eventually).